# Error: Data writes to account failed: Custom error: Max retries exceeded

Tags: solana-cli, deploy, solana-keygen

I though it was a problem with my keypair and tried a fresh deploy and still got the same error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issues I had to close my terminal, restarted my computer, uninstall Solana and reinstalled a it back from fresh.
I will advice anyone having this problem to close the terminal, reopen it and try again.
If the result is not satisfying, restart your computer and try deploying again.
If after restarting, deploy still fails, delete your Solana installation and install it again. see [Solana suite tools](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools)

Happy Hacking.